# Python logging with multiple module imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to establish logging in all modules I'm using. My project structure is

```
# driver.py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class driver:
    ....
```

```
# driver_wrapper.py
from driver import driver

device = driver(...)

def driver_func():
    logging.info("...")
    ....
```

```
# main.py
import logging
import driver_wrapper
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.WARNING)

driver_wrapper.driver_func()
```

My problem now is that I still get INFO level messages and also the output is 'INFO:root'. But I would expect the module name instead of root.

Is there a way to set the logging level in the main.py for all modules or is it already correct how I do it? There are a lot of posts about this problem but the solutions don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your modules that use `logging` should have the `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` line, and thereafter you always log to e.g.`logger.info(...)`, and never call e.g. `logging.info(...)`. The latter is equivalent to logging to the root logger, not the module's logger. That "all your modules" includes `driver_wrapper.py` in your example.